# Save file Javascript with file name

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a text editor in pure Javascript. I'd like it so that when the user clicks the 'Save' button, the editor downloads the file. I've already got this partly working:

```
uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(codeMirror.getValue());
newWindow=window.open(uriContent, 'filename.txt');
```

The file downloads, but the problem is that the file is named 'download'.

**Question**: How could I change the name of the file to be anything I want, e.g `filename.txt`?

Comment: @zzzzBov I think this answer is better than the one you link to because it actually shows a solution for the problem stated.

Comment: @AdriánSalgado, that doesn't make this question any less a duplicate, however that close vote occurred over 2 years ago. As you can see there wasn't enough support to actually close this question. If you think the other question should have a better answer, then I recommend adding one.

Comment: Doesn't seem like any good answer yet! It's just a little blackhole in javascript window object I guess! I have the same concern: my code is going to open the file on the fly that contains the report but the filename is not what my code defines. I should not require the user to click a href and download the file.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit), so close though. I'll have to keep pondering.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Replace your "Save" button with an anchor link and set the new `download` attribute dynamically. Works in Chrome and Firefox:

```
var d = "ha";
$(this).attr("href", "data:image/png;base64,abcdefghijklmnop").attr("download", "file-" + d + ".png");
```

Here's a working example with the name set as the current date: http://jsfiddle.net/Qjvb3/

Here a compatibility table for `download`attribute: http://caniuse.com/download

Comment: download attribute browser support http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: As above, no download attribute support in Safari & IE.

Answer (score 24):

```
function saveAs(uri, filename) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
        document.body.appendChild(link); // Firefox requires the link to be in the body
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = uri;
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link); // remove the link when done
    } else {
        location.replace(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my life bro. Thanks

Comment: We life in the year 2021 now. So my question is, is this still the way to go? This feels a little "hackish".

Answer (score 9):

Use the `filename` property like this:

```
uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream;filename=filename.txt," + 
              encodeURIComponent(codeMirror.getValue());
newWindow=window.open(uriContent, 'filename.txt');
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently, there is no reliable way to do this. See: [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and it's still downloading a file named 'download'.
This is what my code is right now:
`uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream;filename=filename.txt," + encodeURIComponent(codeMirror.getValue());
newWindow=window.open(uriContent, 'filename.txt');`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for the bit of browser testing I've done in Firefox; is this a feature in a different browser? [Wikipedia mentions that Data URL's can't carry filenames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Disadvantages).

Comment: Hmm ok, well thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: This does not work for Firefox. 10.0.9