# jquery - save image as specified filename

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Save file Javascript with file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name)

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WwDdr/3/

On a page I have:

- an Image
- an input box with a string (comes from elsewhere, disregard this essentially)
- an input box with the URL of the image
- a span containing the file extension

How can I:

Click a button/link/whatever that will prompt a "Save As" windows, with the original filename of the image being replaced by the "title" string? Is this possible?

EDIT: Looks like there's no jq solution - can be done with a server side language however.

Comment: The post doesn't seem to have a working solution?

Comment: Thats the point ... there is no cross browser working way of doing this using JavaScript - you could do it using a server side language ...