# Save input text as from form as .vcf

Tags: javascript

Just more of checking if this is possible in JavaScript as that is my favored language. I will have a form that collects certain data and I want to know if I can then save that input to a text file but name it as .vcf to visualise the input see below:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N;LANGUAGE=en-us:Clause;Santa
FN:[]
TITLE:Big Daddy Clause
CATEGORIES:Presents, Santa, Holiday, Christmas
TEL;CELL;VOICE: (999) 555-1212
ADR;TYPE=dom,work,postal,parcel:;;[INPUT]
URL:[INPUT]
EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:[INPUT]
NOTE:[INPUT]
REV:[TODAYS DATE]
END:VCARD
```

I will simply be attempting to create a vcard and send it to someone from an input form so it can be opened into Outlook. I'll figure out actually sending it to an email address in the next phase. Could someone tell me if that is feasible so I can start to build it over the weekend? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write fies using JavaScript. That would be a major security issue writing files to the client.

But you can do something simmelar using a Data URI:

[Save file Javascript with file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name)