# Almost no experience in HTML and JavaScript, Having problems with this simple JSON creator

Tags: javascript, json, html

I want to make a simple website that takes in your name and then creates a JSON file for you to download,

This is what I got so far...

http://liveweave.com/a56GeR

It will create it and ask you where you want to download it, The problem is when the download window pops up the name for download is random and comes with no file extension.

I was hoping I could have it named automatically also with the name given and have .json file extension but I can't find the solution.

Also is it possible for the download to happen automatically to a specific location?

Sorry for the newbie question, first time working with web stuff.

Thank you

Comment: @user1087058 don't worry about asking! specially about "newbie questions". This one was not newbie question by the way! :))

Comment: apparently it's a common question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name