# Exporting Data in Excel, Javascript table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I am using angularjs and exporting data in excel from the table that has been uploaded.

I am using the following code:

`function (e)
    {

    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=exportable]').html()));

e.preventDefault();`

It is allowing me to download the file but extension is missing. Can you pls guide me how to change file name and extension both for the same?

Thanks

Comment: ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name

Comment: Thanks Tim, I tried the same but it doesnt work... Is there any other way I can use that?

Answer (score 0):

## Excel to JSON

This is basically what you are looking for, some way to turn excel to JSON data with JavaScript. [Here](http://psjinx.com/programming/2014/01/04/parsing-excel-workbooks-using-javascript/) is a link to an article about how it can be done using XLSXReader in a web app along with AngularJS.

## Sample Code

```
$(function() {
    $("#xlsxFile").change(function(event) {
        var file = this.files[0],
            sheets;
        XLSXReader(file, true, function(xlsxData) {
            sheets = xlsxData.sheets;
            // Do somehting with sheets. It's a
            // Javascript object with sheet names
            // as keys and data as value in form of 2D array
        });
    });
});
```

## Working Example

[Here](http://code.psjinx.com/xlsx.js/) is a working example of the code. You can upload a `csv` file and have it turned into JSON.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I want to export the data in the java script  table to excel so that I can do some modifications. I am able to acheive that, just I want a filename of my choice along with the extn as per my choice.

Comment: oh I see, sorry I misread. so you want to turn JSON into csv?