# How to change or customized the file of this script.

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel

I have script here who's exporting html file to excel file and can be downloaded. My question is, how to change or modify the filename? because when I downloaded it the filename will appear 'download'.

HERE is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
,template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"                 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>  <x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}<     /x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions>   </x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]-->   </head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
,base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))       }
, format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {         return c[p]; }) }
return function(table, name) {
if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
})()
</script>
```

Below is the sample fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/insin/cmewv/

Please help me thanks.

Comment: [Similar topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/cmewv/3092/

create an `a` element to process the download;

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = "test filename";
link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
link.click();
```

Comment: thanks for the response mr,@amow but my script was already had a download function. it works fine. i just want to modify the filename. any ideas?

Comment: oh,, sorry i didnt test the script before commenting. thanks you sir amow.