# how to rename the downloaded filename in excel export javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

hi all i am using java script working with  excel export download functionality download is working fine now my need is i want to rename the downloaded file name for example now excel name is `download` now i need to change into `custom download` help how to do and get custom name

here i attached my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ode5d340/

Comment: You can try this: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Comment: they use a tag to download in button it's not working in my case @RolandStuder

Comment: @jose Well actually the answers address, that the only solution is to use a tag (which does not have to be shown). So yes I would argue this is an exact duplicate.

Comment: ok @RolandStuder i will remodify my question

Comment: @jose: Why are the provided answers from the duplicate question not viable. It works fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/kpLrgjqq/

Comment: Thanks @RolandStuder