# How to save CSV File React / Spring Boot in Downloads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, opencsv

When I directly access the api in the browser address tab, it automatically downloads the file, but when using the axios get request in the application, it does not save.

I have already set-up the backend (Spring Boot) for the CSV download

I can see the response already on the developer tools but seems it was not saving the .CSV file in Downloads

Here is the response seen on the browser.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="2021-03-10-Calendar.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

In the response, you can see the raw data.

Is there a way to make the response directly save the file?
I use axios get request for the calling of the api.

Comment: The second answer (not accepted answer) is the answer you seek from this duplicate: [Save file Javascript with file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717851/save-file-javascript-with-file-name)