# How to take Screenshot of div in jsp page in IE8

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, screenshot

I want to know **How to create a screenshot of a div(which shows Google chart) in a jsp page which works in IE8**. I have gone through options that works in IE9 or other upgraded browsers. But I need it working  specifically in IE8. Any solutions using any scripting language or using JAVA are welcome.It will be best if anyone can provide me an working example.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use something like this: http://www.battlehorse.net/page/topics/charts/save_google_charts_as_image.html ?

(Found there [Is it possible to save a google chart as an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466157/save-google-chart-as-image))